# Prove this limit of $x^4 + 1/x$ formally

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

prove:

$lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space x^4 + \frac{1}{x} $

So,

$lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space x^4 + \frac{1}{x} = lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space x^4 + lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space \frac{1}{x} $

So, we can prove each of the limits on the RHS is $=1$

**Part 1:**

Prove: $lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space x^4 = 1 $ We must find a $\delta$

$|x^4 - 1| < \epsilon$ for some $|x - 1| < \delta_1$

$|x^4 - 1| = |x^2 + 1||x-1||x+1|$

Lets require, $|x - 1| < 1$ Therefore,

$|x| - |1| < |x - 1| < 1 \implies |x| < 2 \implies |x^2 + 1| < 5$

$|x + 1| < |x| + |1| < 3$

$|x^2 + 1||x+1| < 15$

If $|x - 1| < \epsilon/15$ then

$|x^2 + 1||x+1||x-1| < 15(\epsilon/15) = \epsilon$ therefore,

$\delta_1 = \text{min}\space (1, \epsilon/15)$

**Part 2:**

Prove $lim_{x\to 1} \space \space \space \frac{1}{x} = 1 $

-> Let's require $|x - 1| < 1$ find $\delta_2$ such that $|1/x - 1| < \epsilon$

$|1/x - 1| = |1 - x| < \epsilon(|x|)$

$|x| - |1| < |x - 1| < 1 \implies |x| < 2 \implies 1/|x| > 1/2$ Therefore,

$|-(x - 1)| < |x|\epsilon$

$|x - 1| < |x|\epsilon$

$|x - 1| < \epsilon$

here, I get stuck. I don't know how to prove this second part.

Help!!

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

For part 2), first let $\delta = \text{min}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}, \epsilon/2 \right)$, then if $|x-1| < \delta \longrightarrow \left|\dfrac{1}{x} - 1\right| = \dfrac{|1-x|}{|x|} < \dfrac{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \epsilon$